# rendering the values of reactjs objects without knowing the keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am quite new to reactjs and am trying to render the data retrieved by an API call in reactjs. However, I am getting the following error:

"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {key1, key2}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

This is my code:

```
function App() {
  const [returnedData, setReturnedData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const newData = await fetch("/api", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    }).then((res) => res.json());
    setReturnedData(newData);
  };

  fetchData();
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {Object.keys(returnedData).map((item, index) => (
          <h2 key={index}>{returnedData[Number(item)]}</h2>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );

}

export default App;
```

I would appreciate it if you let me know how to solve this problem! Basically, how I should render data without already knowing the keys? Because I only have access to keys after running the code.

The purpose of this program, is to retrieve data from a SQL server database. For this purpose, I am using express and mssql packages. This is the code that has to run on the server side:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const dbOperation = require('./dbFiles/dbOperation');

const API_PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.use(cors());

app.post('/api', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Called!")
    const result = await dbOperation.getData();
    res.send(result);
});

app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${API_PORT}`));
```

And the following code is used to get the data from the database:

```
const config = require('./dbConfig');
const sql = require('mssql');

const getData = async() => {
    try{
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let allData = await pool.request().query("SELECT * from Alerts");
        return allData;
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
module.exports = {
    getData
}
```

Comment: What's the value of returnedData?

Comment: @HenryDev I logged the value of returnedData and this is what I'm getting: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: that's the issue right there. You're trying to use Object.keys on [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @HenryDev Thanks. I would appreciate if you suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your code, it will cause an infinite loop。you cannot `setState` inside `render`. Modified the code like:

If data is an Object like {key1: 1, key2:2}.

```js
function App() {
  const [returnedData, setReturnedData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const newData = await fetch("/api", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
      }).then((res) => res.json())
      setReturnedData(newData)
    };
  
    fetchData();
  }, [])

  
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {Object.keys(returnedData).map((item, index) => (
          <h2 key={item}>{returnedData[item]}</h2>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );

}

export default App;
```

If data is an Array like [1, 2], change return to:

```js
return (
    <>
      <div>
        {returnedData.map((item, index) => (
          // if item is an Object, you should use item.xxx to get anything you want. An Object child is not valid.
          <h2 key={index}>{item}</h2>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
);
```

In this code, we use the useEffect hook to fetch the data from the server when the component is mounted. We also use the useState hook to keep track of the returned data.

The return block uses the map method to iterate over the returned data and generate the corresponding HTML elements. We check the data type of each item to decide whether to render the item as a string or an object.

I hope this helps!